# React JS input field not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a contact form using React JS and this is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Create extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeFirstname = this.onChangeFirstname.bind(this);
        this.onChangeLastname = this.onChangeLastname.bind(this);
        this.onChangeMessage = this.onChangeMessage.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            person_firstname: '',
            person_lastname: '',
            message:''
        }
    }
    onChangeFirstname(e) {
      this.setState({
        person_firstname: e.target.value
      });
    }
    onChangeLastname(e) {
      this.setState({
        person_lastname: e.target.value
      })  
    }
    onChangeMessage(e) {
      this.setState({
        message: e.target.value
      })
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(`The values are ${this.state.person_firstname}, ${this.state.person_lastname}, and ${this.state.message}`)
      this.setState({
        person_firstname: '',
        person_lastname: '',
        message: ''
      })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <h3>Contact Form</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>First Name:  </label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" 
                            onChange={this.onChangeFirstName}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.onChangeLastname}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Message: </label>
                        <textarea className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.onChangeMessage}>
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Everything seems fine, but the code gives a wrong result.
When I enter the following,
[image]

I get the following result

[image]

No matter what I enter in the first name field, it is ignored and I get a blank in the result.
I tried moving the Lastname input field above the Firstname input field and I still get the first input (Lastname) as blank in the console.

Comment: In your component onChange you are referencing some onChangeFirstName, which doesn't exist. Although onChangeFirstname does exist ;)

Comment: :facepalm: thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

i refactor your code and everything looks fine ...

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      message: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(this.state);

    this.setState({
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      message: ""
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>First Name: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstname"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Last Name: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastname"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Message: </label>
            <textarea
              name="message"
              className="form-control"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo, `onChangeFirstname` should have a capital N `onChangeFirstName`